# $P{LoggedInUsername} and data from a user in a WITH-clause

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using JasperSoft Reports v.6.2.1 and when running a report within the Studio preview the output comes after 2 seconds.

Running the same report (output xlsx) on the server takes > half a minute - though there is no data volume issue (crosstab, 500 lines, 17 columns in excel,  "ignore pagination" = true).

I am using `$P{LoggedInUsername}` to filter data within the `WHERE`-part of a `WITH`-clause (based on the user's rights), run the report and realized, when using a fixed value (the user's id as a string) instead of the parameter in the query, the report execution speed is good.

Same against Oracle DB from SQL Developer - the query resultset with a user's id string is back in 2 sec.

Also the output of `$P{LoggedInUsername}` in a `TextField` produces a String.

Once switching back to the `$P{LoggedInUsername}`-parameter in the query, the report takes ages again or runs out of heap memory in the Studio/server.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally my problem was solved using the expression `user_id = '$P!{LoggedInUsername}'` instead of `$P{LoggedInUsername}` in the `WHERE`-part of my query.